# Очистка состояния redux

Tags: javascript, redux

Возможно ли очистить redux? Чтобы все пришло к начальному состоянию.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, но только руцями. Мой пример ниже но так же можете прочесть ответ от [Dan Abramov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/458193/dan-abramov) сосоздателя `Redux` [How to reset the state of a Redux store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622588/how-to-reset-the-state-of-a-redux-store/35641992#35641992)

1. Создаете `action` который будет вызываться тогда когда надо вернуться в изначальное состояние `reduser'(а/ов)`.
2. В каждом `redusers` создаете к примеру `case 'DEFAULT_STATE': return initialState` где DEFAULT_STATE может являться типом а `defaultState` это ваше изначальное состояние `reduser'a`.

**К примеру:**

```js
// Clear store action
const DEFAULT_STATE = 'DEFAULT_STATE';

export function ClearStore() { // вызываете ClearStore там где Вам это нужно. К примеру при logout пользователя.
  return {
    type: DEFAULT_STATE,
  };
}

// Redusers
const defaultState = {
  list: [],
  data: {},
  pagination: {
    page: 1,
    perPage: 10,
  },
  loading: true,
};

export default (state = defaultState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CLEAR_DATA: // вызываете CLEAR_DATA в каждом из redusers или там где Вам нужно.
      return defaultState;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: Зачем в каждом, если корневой может снести всё?